# Help about checking or comparing two lists

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have List A with a look-up dropdown from List B. How can I achieve to check who hasn't submit an entry yet?

For example, if my List B has 10 people, List A should have 10 entries.

Can this be achieve using Workflow?

Comment: Can you be more specific with regards to the columns you have in your lists and what you mean by "who hasn't submit an entry yet"?

Comment: List B has 100 names, These 100 people must submit one entry per person in List A so I want a checker to compare the two lists who hasn't submitted an entry yet. Just for example,  List A will have a Name Lookup column (the name lookup with be from List B) and travel columns. List B with name, bday, address columns.

Answer (score 1):

You could load these two lists up in Excel and do the comparison there.

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(<single column I value>,<entire column E range>,1,FALSE)),FALSE, TRUE)
```

This will check cell in Column I against the range of values in Column E, and set the value to True or False.  Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315551/find-if-value-in-column-a-contains-value-from-column-b

You could automate this some with PowerPivot and daily refresh, otherwise, you can save the excel file and just refresh the data manually when you open the workbook.